# Copy div content to textarea and preserving code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69nxx/6/

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <span title="&lt;test&gt;">abc &lt; &amp;lt;</span> <span></span>      
</div>
```

I wish to get the exact code from the div inside the textarea.
Is this possible?

As you can see the entities in title are converted.

I don't need a 100% jquery solution.
I need this in firefox.

Comment: ... your code appears to be working for me as-is in chrome.

Comment: sorry, I need this in firefox

Comment: Right, but what this shows is that the problem is a cross-browser problem, so whatever you do to fix it in firefox may break what it does in chrome, or IE, etc. do you only care about firefox?

Comment: danip your code is working.I have used firefox.

Comment: @mohan, what firefox version/os are you using ?

Comment: It appears as though the conversion from &lt; to < is happening when firefox parses the html, meaning the only way you can get it in it's previous form is to get it before firefox parses the html (which isn't possible in this case because it's hardcoded)

Comment: Just a thought: Have you tried prepending a <pre> and appending a </pre> before extracting the content..?

Comment: @T4NK3R No matter what you do to the html, it doesn't change the fact that the browser has already taken the source html and morphed it into what it expects it to be. Using `<pre></pre>` to begin with would solve the problem, however, how would that affect the fact that we are working within a content editable? Wrapping what is currently in the div with a `pre` using javascript does not work for the reason mentioned above.